# GeoServer / OpenLayers : Front-End interface

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I am using GeoServer as cartographic server.

I'd like to make a client side interface using OpenLayers, Ext, GeoExt. 
That can select by attributes the layers published on GeoServer as WMS, and display the result on a map (OpenStreetMap).

Which IDE to use for this purpose: NetBeans or Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Openlayers is just a JavaScript library, so you can use whichever Integrated Development Environment (IDE) you feel most comfortable using for web development.

If you are using a Java web framework then [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/) would be an ideal choice as its primarily for developing in Java.

Its also worth checking out the [JetBrains IDE's](https://www.jetbrains.com/#products-all).

Edited to answer your comment:

There is no need to integrate GeoServer into your web application. GeoSever works as an  independent service and produces [WMS (Web Map Services)](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) for your [OpenLayers frontend](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html) to consume.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Once I deployed Netbeans with Tomcat , how can i integrate GEOSERVER in it ?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the clarifications. I chose working with Eclipse. I create a html web-page to display a map .

whitch references Openlayers with <script src="/lib/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript">, (this library is under WEB-INF/lib).

The page doesn't run. Is this right approach or Am I missing some dependencies ?

Thanks for support

Comment: I did a lot of projects with ExtJS 4.2, OpenLayers 2 and GeoExt2 in Javascript. Check the source code in the browser if the path of the openlayers is set correctly. It would be useful  if you share your code.

Comment: @ImaneKtb I can't help you any further without your code. You need to investigate further with firebug/developer tools.